# MySQL - Transactional Bound with multiple stored proc calls and easy way to rollback?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

first time poster

So my issue/question is this.  I have a stored proc that is doing some "stuff".  Within this "stuff", I am calling other stored procs as well that are doing "additional stuff".

I want to be able to set the auto commit to OFF in the main SP.

```
SET SESSION autocommit = 0;
```

Question is, when the other SPs get called, will it also still obey the autocommit=0?  If not and I have to set it manully, how do I ensure the rollback works?

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_whatever ()

BEGIN
    SET SESSION autocommit = 0;
    DECLARE track_no INT DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, NOT FOUND, SQLWARNING;
    -- Error Handling Block
        errorHandling:BEGIN
            
                ROLLBACK;
                GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @`errno` = MYSQL_ERRNO, @`sqlstate` = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @`text` = MESSAGE_TEXT;
                SET @full_error = CONCAT('ERROR ', @`errno`, ' (', @`sqlstate`, '): ', @`text`);
                SELECT track_no, @full_error;
            
            END errorHandling;
                
START TRANSACTION;
     DO SOME SELECTS;
     DO SOME DMLS;
     Call some stored_proc();   
     DO SOME MORE SELECTS;
     DO SOME MORE DMLS;
     Call some additional stored_proc_additional();

  COMMIT;       
        
END;
```

If an error occurs within this sp_whatever proc or in the stored_proc() or stored_proc_additional(), will it rollback the whole transaction or just what is in the local procedure where the error occured.  What is best practice to either make it so I can rollback the whole transaction if I am calling other procs when an error occurs?  Is this even possible?

If I collapse all my SP into one massive SP, then the issue becomes within each BEGIN...END Block, I am unable to use a PREPARE STATEMENT due to the MySQL docs mentioning:

> Because local variables are in scope only during stored program execution, references to them are not permitted in prepared statements created within a stored program. Prepared statement scope is the current session, not the stored program, so the statement could be executed after the program ends, at which point the variables would no longer be in scope. For example, SELECT ... INTO local_var cannot be used as a prepared statement.

Any advice/Thoughts?

Calling multiple Stored Procs but unable to rollback the whole transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a catch-all-error exit handler to rollback in the main procedure, it works on all procedures within it when they send an error message.Take this case below for example. We have a procedure `n1` which inserts numeric values 1 to 5 into our test table's PK column. Then we have procedure `n2` which inserts 6 to 10, but it then inserts number 5 to the table, which raises a duplicate PK value error. Next, in our main SP `nn` we put those beforementioned procedures under the `START TRANSACTION` section and add some other stuff besides them.

```
create table test (id int primary key);
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists n1 //
drop procedure if exists n2 //
drop procedure if exists nn //

create procedure n1()
begin
declare n int default 1;
while n<=5 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//

create procedure n2()
begin
declare n int default 6;
while n<=10 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;
insert test values(5); -- this raises a dup pk value error

end//


create procedure nn()
begin
declare exit handler for sqlexception 
begin  
rollback; 
resignal;
end;

truncate test;

start transaction ;
insert test values(100);
call n1;
insert test values(200);
call n2;
insert test values(300);
commit;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Let's call the main procedure:

```
call nn;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'

select * from test;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

As the result shows, the whole session is rolled back.

To wrap up, within your main procedure, if you have predefined an exit handler to rollback when an error is found, it applies to all the nested procedures under a transaction when they raise an err message , which can be regarded as an ALL-OR-NOTHING job.

But, this is not the end of it. What if we mute the error notification from a sub SP ? For example, we declare an exit handler in `n2` but does not define the `RESIGNAL` statement, which will make `n2` sends a `query ok` notice to the outside instead of unmasking the true event. Check this out:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists n1 //
drop procedure if exists n2 //
drop procedure if exists nn //

create procedure n1()
begin
declare n int default 1;
while n<=5 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//

create procedure n2()
begin
declare n int default 6;
declare exit handler for sqlexception begin end;

while n<=10 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;
insert test values(5); -- this raises a dup pk value error

end//


create procedure nn()
begin
declare exit handler for sqlexception 
begin  
rollback; 
resignal;
end;

truncate test;

start transaction ;
insert test values(100);
call n1;
insert test values(200);
call n2;
insert test values(300);
commit;
end//

delimiter ;

call nn;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

 select * from test;

+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   4 |
|   5 |
|   6 |
|   7 |
|   8 |
|   9 |
|  10 |
| 100 |
| 200 |
| 300 |
+-----+
```

As we can see, since the error message is no longer received in the main SP `nn`,  its exit handler will no longer be triggered, thus no rollback is performed.

In other words , you can tweak the sub SP to make it work to your favour like muting error message from certain SP which we just did. You can even customise error code in different SP and declare specific handlers in the main SP to address each code. It's for you to decide.

But beware, a commit or rollback from a nested SP also applies to the outside. In the simplified example below (no condition hanlder declared this time) , `n2` has a rollback at the end which not only works on itself but spreads outside as well.

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists n1 //
drop procedure if exists n2 //
drop procedure if exists nn //

create procedure n1()
begin
declare n int default 1;

while n<=5 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//

create procedure n2()
begin
declare n int default 6;

while n<=10 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

rollback;

end//


create procedure nn()
begin

truncate test;

start transaction ;
insert test values(100);
call n1;
insert test values(200);
call n2; -- there is a rollback at the end of the procedure
insert test values(300);
commit;
end//

delimiter ;

 call nn;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

select * from test;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 300 |
+-----+
```

As denoted above, the rollback from `n2` undoes all changes in the  transaction so far.

Finally, please be care when setting autocommit off. As its effect lasts as long as the session stays until toggled on. It may potentially give rise to loss of data when the mind intends the behaviors of autocommit. Use of `START TRANSACTION` is safer in this regard.

**UPDATED with procedure n2.1 thrown in n2**

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists n1 //
drop procedure if exists n2 //
drop procedure if exists `n2.1` //
drop procedure if exists nn //

create procedure n1()
begin
declare n int default 1;

while n<=5 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//

create procedure `n2.1`()
begin
insert test values(999);
end//

create procedure n2()
begin
declare n int default 6;

call `n2.1`;
while n<=10 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//


create procedure nn()
begin

truncate test;

start transaction ;
insert test values(100);
call n1;
insert test values(200);
call n2; 
insert test values(300);
commit;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Let's call it:

```
call nn;

select * from test;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   4 |
|   5 |
|   6 |
|   7 |
|   8 |
|   9 |
|  10 |
| 100 |
| 200 |
| 300 |
| 999 |
+-----+
```

In addition, to demonstrate if a SQLEXCEPTION from 3 levels deep can be handled by outside handler, I'm purposely making `n2.1` blunder. Then let's see if the exit handler in our main `nn` will deal with it.

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists n1 //
drop procedure if exists n2 //
drop procedure if exists `n2.1` //
drop procedure if exists nn //

create procedure n1()
begin
declare n int default 1;

while n<=5 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//

create procedure `n2.1`()
begin
insert test values(999);
insert test values(999);
end//

create procedure n2()
begin
declare n int default 6;

call `n2.1`;
while n<=10 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//


create procedure nn()
begin
declare exit handler for sqlexception 
begin  
commit; 
resignal;
end;
truncate test;

start transaction ;
insert test values(100);
call n1;
insert test values(200);
call n2; 
insert test values(300);
commit;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Now the moment of truth.

```
call nn;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '999' for key 'PRIMARY'
select * from test;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   4 |
|   5 |
| 100 |
| 200 |
| 999 |
+-----+
```

As the result depicts, it turns out the exit handler in `nn` took care of the error from `n2.1` by committing changes so far and signaling the error message before terminating the procedure.

And now, in the event that you wonder what happens if both `n2` and `nn` have handlers. I've also prepared two more cases for you. In case 1, `n2` mutes the error by removing the `resignal` in its handler, while in case 2, `n2` announces the error with the `resignal` in its handler. Note, in both cases, `n2` uses continue handler this time .

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists n1 //
drop procedure if exists n2 //
drop procedure if exists `n2.1` //
drop procedure if exists nn //

create procedure n1()
begin
declare n int default 1;

while n<=5 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//

create procedure `n2.1`()
begin
insert test values(999);
insert test values(999);
end//

create procedure n2()
begin
declare n int default 6;
declare continue handler for sqlexception 
begin  
rollback; 
end;

call `n2.1`;
while n<=10 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//


create procedure nn()
begin
declare exit handler for sqlexception 
begin  
commit; 
resignal;
end;
truncate test;

start transaction ;
insert test values(100);
call n1;
insert test values(200);
call n2; 
insert test values(300);
commit;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Here is the result for case 1:

```
call nn;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

select * from test;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   6 |
|   7 |
|   8 |
|   9 |
|  10 |
| 300 |
+-----+
```

As the result reflects, the `n2` rolled back changes so far and moved on (withouting raising an error due to the absence of `resignal`). And `nn` just carried on as if nothing abnormal had happened so far.

Now if you are still with me, here comes case 2. Pay attention to the contents of handlers as `n2` has commit and resignal , while `nn` has rollback (and resignal for the sake of notification).

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists n1 //
drop procedure if exists n2 //
drop procedure if exists `n2.1` //
drop procedure if exists nn //

create procedure n1()
begin
declare n int default 1;

while n<=5 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//

create procedure `n2.1`()
begin
insert test values(999);
insert test values(999);
end//

create procedure n2()
begin
declare n int default 6;
declare continue handler for sqlexception 
begin  
commit; 
resignal;
end;

call `n2.1`;
while n<=10 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//


create procedure nn()
begin
declare exit handler for sqlexception 
begin  
rollback; 
resignal;
end;
truncate test;

start transaction ;
insert test values(100);
call n1;
insert test values(200);
call n2; 
insert test values(300);
commit;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Now we are getting the truth in case 2.

```
call nn;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '999' for key 'PRIMARY'

select * from test;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   4 |
|   5 |
| 100 |
| 200 |
| 999 |
+-----+
```

So `n2` committed the changes up until now as well as cried an error. **HERE IS A BOOKMARK WHICH WE WILL COME BACK SHORTLY AFTER.** Upon receiving the error, `nn` performed a rollback, which of course could not undo the changes already commited by `n2`, and called off the rest.

Now let's get back to the bookmark. What do you think really happened when `n2` shouted the error? Because for its continue handler, it should carry on its job due to the handler action being `continue`. But the handler from `nn` would just rollback things and kill the current procedure. Check the code below to find out. Note there is a commit at the end of `n2` so as to make a proof of things truly having happened.

```
 
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists n1 //
drop procedure if exists n2 //
drop procedure if exists `n2.1` //
drop procedure if exists nn //

create procedure n1()
begin
declare n int default 1;

while n<=5 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;

end//

create procedure `n2.1`()
begin
insert test values(999);
insert test values(999);
end//

create procedure n2()
begin
declare n int default 6;
declare continue handler for sqlexception 
begin  
commit; 
resignal;
end;

call `n2.1`;
while n<=10 do
insert test values(n);
set n=n+1;
end while;
commit;
end//


create procedure nn()
begin
declare exit handler for sqlexception 
begin  
rollback; 
resignal;
end;
truncate test;

start transaction ;
insert test values(100);
call n1;
insert test values(200);
call n2; 
insert test values(300);
commit;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Lo and behold, here the curtain unveils.

```
call nn;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '999' for key 'PRIMARY'

select * from test;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   4 |
|   5 |
| 100 |
| 200 |
| 999 |
+-----+
```

It ends up `n2` did not get to finish the rest of its procedure with the handler action `continue`. Which means, the exit handler in main procedure `nn` repealed everything as soon as it received the error from `n2` but not before executing its rollback and resignal duty.

It's a long read which I pray did not bore you too much. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: This is an amazing reply with excellent details.  Love the attention to details and the examples given.  For my use, the first example is exactly what I need.  I need an all or nothing approach.  My issue was I have the commit in the sub SP.  I need to remove them out and allow the main SP to handle the commit/rollback as well as the error handling.  I will give this all a try and let you know how it proceeds.

Comment: So I am noticing something odd.
Using your example above.  I have  procs n1 and n2 and nn.  Also n2 calls n2.1.  So really I am calling procs 3 levels deep.  Is this allowed?  Cause when it gets to n2 and it calls n2.1, it just stops.  No errors.  Just exits out.  Well no error is getting reported back to the handler.  Is this a limitation in MySQL?

Comment: How come it doesn't work? Please check the updated section with `n2.1` added. By the way, if you are using `n2.1` as the SP's name, please make sure surround it with a pair of backticks. Otherwise, MySQL misinterprets it as `DBname`.`SPname`.

Comment: I also added an instance in which a handler in the main procedure can manage an error coming from 3 layers deep.

Comment: And a lot more has been added, which more than doubled the original content. This should be ample enough for now : )

Comment: Excellent, all makes sense now and I have my procs all working correctly now.  Much appreciated for the detailed answer.